# Vue I18n HTML-Interpolation

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I have an array of all product features in json file with translations. Each locale string in `en.json` has some parts of the string highlighted somehow like **bold** or *italic*.

```json
{
  "feature1": "bla bla bla <b>blabla</b> bla ... bla bla",
  "feature2": "<i>bla</i> bla <b>bla bla bla</b> bla ... <b>bla bla</b>"
}
```

I want to render them in a list but **without using** `v-html` because it's not recommended.

I tried [component interpolation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#component-interpolation) but it didn't help, I tried putting `<b>` and `<i>` inside a named slot but it didn't work because I tried to put opening and closing tags to different named slots and that led to a **not valid HTML markup**.

```json
{
  "feature1": "bla bla bla {b}blabla{bclose} bla ... bla bla",
  "feature2": "bla bla {b}bla bla bla{bclose} bla ... {b}bla bla{bclose}"
}
```

```html
<template>
  <i18n
   tag="li"
   v-for="feature in $i18n.messages.en.features"
   path="features"
  >
    <template v-slot:b>
      <b>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:bclose>
      </b>
    </template>
    ...
  </i18n>
</template>
```

the end result I'm trying to reach will look like this

- bla bla bla **blabla** bla ... bla bla
- *bla* bla **bla bla bla** bla ... **bla bla**

How could I achieve what I want to achieve but **without using** `v-html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you should do that is to keep all your HTML in your `<template>` block, and all your text in your i18n, and you'll have to tease apart those strings inside the HTML block into separate translations:

```html
<i18n tag="li" path="features">
  <b>{{ $t('bla bla') }}</b>
</i18n>
```

```json
{
  "features": "lorem ipsum {0} ...",
  "bla bla": "bar baz"
}
```

This results in:

```html
<li>lorem ipsum <b>bar baz</b> ...</li>
```

It's a bit unfortunate that you need `bla bla` as separate word, but you need it as standalone block, you can't just transpose the HTML start and end tags into your string, as that would be the same as unsafe string interpolation.

Comment: This is unfortunate but I guess there isn't really other way around. I was trying to avoid separating it as well

Comment: See https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component.html#basic-usage for more details

Answer (score 1):

I think using `v-html` directive is not a problem if you are using trusted content, for example, your i18n file is in your control and hosted by you. Most XSS attacks or issues come from third-party requests, it doesn't seem to be your case. You can read further information about this directive and XSS [here](https://dev.to/nandod1707/should-you-care-about-xss-in-vuejs-1ea6).

In case you are interested on using it, you can do what is proposed here, basically [you have to sanitize the content first](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6333#issuecomment-321457721).